# Stripe is not recognized by the terminal in VS CODE

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, next.js, stripe-payments

Upon running 'stripe listen' command in terminal in VS Code, it throws an issue :-

The term 'stripe' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.

Can anybody help me in resolving this?

I have already configured Stripe-CLI for my project using command prompt but it is not working in the terminal of vs code.

Comment: If you want to run Stripe globally then it has to be installed globally. Did you follow [these](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli) steps? What system are you using, what command prompt and terminal are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can restart your vscode and then try running your command, if it is running in command prompt outside of vscode. VScode terminal uses available system CLIs like command prompt,powershell & others, so whatever is running outside of vscode terminal, should run in vscode terminal as well.

If your command is not running outside of vscode as well, you can check the PATH variable in your system environment variables (search for environment variables in start menu, assuming Windows OS), whether it contains the path to the folder containing stripe executable file or not. You can add the path if it is not present, then restart your terminals/vscode and try running your command.

Comment: It is not working even after working int cmd prompt it is not working in the terminal of VS code